# How to use Xsoup to convert Xpath to CSS selector?

Tags: java, jsoup, xsoup

I am using Jsoup for HTML parsing, but as Jsoup doesn't support Xpath selector, hence I am using [Xsoup](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup) which is Jsoup use Xpath as selector.
In the github's ReadMe page: The example given:

```
@Test
    public void testSelect() {

        String html = "<html><div><a href='https://github.com'>github.com</a></div>" +
                "<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr></table></html>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

        String result = Xsoup.compile("//a/@href").evaluate(document).get();
        Assert.assertEquals("https://github.com", result);

        List<String> list = Xsoup.compile("//tr/td/text()").evaluate(document).list();
        Assert.assertEquals("a", list.get(0));
        Assert.assertEquals("b", list.get(1));
    }
```

Can someone please explain what need to be changed in this code to work. I already ensured that I added required library asertj.jar and jsoup.jar

Comment: "How it will work" for what ? for "real html" ? ^^

Comment: @azro: In the github link, only this code snippet is given without context. I want to know how I can use xsoup in standalone form.

Comment: You're unclear, I don't see ANY obstacles around you to try what you need to do

Comment: @azro: I got the answer, those Assert statements were confusing. Thanks for help !!

Comment: I posted a simple working snippet, if it helps someone.. Good then !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working standalone snippet:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import us.codecraft.xsoup.Xsoup;

public class TestXsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args){

            String html = "<html>
                              <div> <a href='https://github.com'>github.com</a> </div>
                              <table><tr>
                                       <td>a</td> 
                                       <td>b</td> 
                              </tr></table> 
                            </html>";

            Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

            List<String> filasFiltradas = Xsoup.compile("//tr/td/text()").evaluate(document).list();
            System.out.println(filasFiltradas);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b]
```

Libraries included:

1. xsoup-0.3.1.jar
2. jsoup-1.103.jar